# How to avoid clearing the previously drawn points in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to draw an image, pixel by pixel at run time. I use QPainter and paintEvent to draw. But when paintEvent is called each time, the previously drawn image is cleared and the new point has been drawn.

How to avoid clearing the previously drawn parts? I just want to append the new pixel point to the previously drawn points.

```
Lines::Lines(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateStatus()));
    m_timer->start();
    m_x = 0;
    m_y = 0;
}

void Lines::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPen pen(Qt::black, 2, Qt::SolidLine);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(pen);
    painter.drawPoint(m_x, m_y);    
}

void Lines::updateStatus()
{
    m_x++;
    m_y++;
    update();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`paintEvent` is supposed to do a complete redraw of the widget region specified in the event.
So you are responsible for buffering previous results.

It doesn't really make sense to *change* the desired output in paintEvent, as it may be randomly called and when it is called is out of your control.

If you want to avoid that you can use a [QGraphicsView](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html).

Buffering could be done using a `QPixmap`, which would be part of the `Lines` class. You draw the pixel in the pixmap (not in the paint event, in updateStatus), and draw the pixmap in the paint event.

Answer (score 1):

`QWidget::setAttribute( WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true );`

prevents clearing the widget. However, this is just for optimization in case the widget does a complete repaint anyway.

You should follow Dr. Hirsch's advice.